# How to set the array values that depend on their key names

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a bit new to PHP, so the question may be obvious, but..

Is it possible to create an array and assign its values using the names of keys like in this wierd example

```
$arr = array (
    "foo" => $this_key_name." some text added",
    "bar" => $this_key_name." some text added",
    "foobar" => "this is left unchanged",
)
```

Of course, by **$this_key_name** I mean some "imaginary and desired property", that contain the key, i.e. the string that represents it.

Having only few keys similar to "foo" and "bar" it really doesn't make a trouble. But say their quantinty is above 20 and they are not so short. Copypasting such templated values would be much easier, than retyping each of them, eh?

The idea to leave them blank and set values after, looping through `foreach()` seems ok, but needs additional check if not every element shoud be processed.

So the question is: **Does there exist any property that contains the current array's key name, that can be accessed during the values' assignment?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way of doing this in PHP since the array keys are not actually created at the time you are trying to read `this_key_name`.  Instead, I would opt for the `foreach` loop which is still relatively simple.

```
$arr = array(
    "foo" => '$this_key_name some text added'
);

array_walk($arr, function (&$value, $key) {
    $value = str_replace('$this_key_name', $key, $value);
});
```

Comment: In such case using a replaced string pattern is the best solution I can imagine. Also it's a nice bypass of checking the true/false-conditions whether to change the value or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The one-word answer is **no**.

You could either use some placeholder and replace it afterwards, or otherwise use a helper function such as:

```
function makeItems(array $keys, $valueFormat)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $result[$key] = sprintf($valueFormat, $key);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Now you can get the desired result with

```
$arr = makeItems(["foo", "bar"], "%s some text added") +
       ['foobar' => 'this is left unchanged'];
```

Of course going this route means you can no longer initialize the array statically (e.g. this won't work when declaring a class property), but you would have the same drawback even if there was some built-in mechanism to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables as key names, but you cannot reference the key name. Like so:

```
$name1 = 'foo';
$name2 = 'bar';
$name3 = 'baz';

$array = array(
    $name1 => $name1.'string 1',
    $name2 => $name2.'string 2',
    $name3 => $name3
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in property that would reflect the key name as it is being assigned.

Your simplest solution might be--as you may have already guessed--building the array and then looping through to make the assignment.

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    $arr[$key] = $key . ' some text added';
}
```